# Cannot access any indexes for array but array works correctly when logged in entirety

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a function `foo` that takes in an array of objects called `locations` and has a string, `fourSquareUrl`, containing information to access the Foursquare API. I grab the data from the API and push it to the `locationData` array.

When I try to access an index of the array, `locationData[i]`, I get undefined. But when I console.log(locationData); the array is displayed correctly. Thanks for your help!

```
var locationData = [];
function foo(locations) {
    for (x in locations) {
        var fourSquareUrl = 'API information';
        $.getJSON(fourSquareUrl, function(data) {
                var foursquareLocation = data.response.venues;
                if(foursquareLocation) {
                    var item = foursquareLocation[0];
                    if (item) {
                        var address = item.location.formattedAddress;
                        locationData.push(address);
                    }
                    else {
                        var noAddress = "No location data available";
                        locationData.push(noAddress);
                    }
                }
        })
    }
}

// works correctly
console.log(locationData);

// results in 'undefined'
console.log(locationData[0]);
```

Comment: Yes is the async function, you should add the console.log inside the callback function (block `$.getJSON(fourSquareUrl, function(data) {`)  to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The address which is retrieved is probably undefined. You should check this way if it is the case:
var locationData = [];

```
function foo(locations) {
    for (x in locations) {
        var fourSquareUrl = 'API information';
        $.getJSON(fourSquareUrl, function(data) {
                var foursquareLocation = data.response.venues;
                if(foursquareLocation) {
                    var item = foursquareLocation[0];
                    if (item) {
                        var address = item.location.formattedAddress;
                        if (!address) {
                          console.log('Empty address is returned');
                        }
                        locationData.push(address);
                    }
                    else {
                        var noAddress = "No location data available";
                        locationData.push(noAddress);
                    }
                }
        })
    }
}

// works correctly
console.log(locationData);

// results in 'undefined'
console.log(locationData[0]);
```